# Counting occurrences across a record in ArcGIS 10.0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, attribute-joins

I'm a student at Millersville University, PA studying for a BA in Geography with a concentration in GIS. I've stumbled across this site for questions I've had over the past year or so with getting introduced to ArcGIS.

I have come across a problem that I can't figure out and my textbook didn't offer any help so I'm hoping one of you can.

I have a table which consists of 3 attribute joins, and I have a text field which has 2 unique values. I want to create a field in which I can summarize the number of times a particular text occurs.

For Example: `Jx = Join #`

```
ObjectID 1 |J1: A | J2: A | J3: B | CountFldA: 2
ObjectID 2 |J1: B | J2: B | J3: A | CountFldA: 1
```

I have a feeling that the answer lies somewhere in python but I have no formal experience in it.

Comment: welcome to the site! Have you taken a look at the [frequency](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001w000000) tool?

Comment: @ Stephen Lead Close, the frequency is defined on the link you gave as 
`_"Reads a table and a set of fields and creates a new table containing unique field values and the number of occurrences of each unique field value."_` What I'm looking for is the frequency across the record. Instead of counting down, I'm counting across. Complicated by the fact that it's a text field.

Comment: ah, that makes sense - sorry I missed that crucial detail. The way to approach this will be to iterate through each record using an ArcPy SearchCursor, and analyse the values in-memory. I'll write some pseudo-code in the morning if you haven't solved it by then :)

Comment: Rayner's answer is great - I should have said "one way to approach this" since his is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate multiple fields together into a new combined field and use 'InStr' inside the Field Calculator (VBScript) to count the number of occurrences of a specific character or string.  For example, instr([Combined],"A") would return the number of "A"s in the Combined field.  Or I suppose you could use InStr on each individual joined field and then add them up.  instr([Field1],"A") + instr([Field2,"A") and so on.

Comment: Perfect @Rayner! This did exactly what I wanted... The VBscript ended up looking like:

`InStr( [cd111.PARTY] , "Democrat") + InStr( [cd110.PARTY], "Democrat" ) +InStr( [cd109.PARTY] , "Democrat" )`